# creating multiple threads to upload to s3

Tags: java, multithreading

I am uploading files to s3 using amazons s3 web service.

It takes about 1 second per file, is there a way I could fire up multiple threads to do this in parallel?

Say I have a method that does the upload call:

public void uploadToS3(string filename);

how can I call fire up 3 threads and each make this call?

Comment: if it only takes one second per file, it might be that the initialization overhead for an ftp connection is quite high compared to time uploading. why not try batching all of the files (say into a zip) and do an upload once?

Comment: Are the uploads using HTTP, FTP, or something else entirely?

Comment: its a web service call using amazon's api

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap your function in a `Runnable` interface

```
public Runnable getS3UploadTask () {
   return new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           uploadToS3();
       }
   };
}
```

and, then you can create as many threads as you please to execute the Runnable:

```
public void startS3Tasks(int workerCnt) {
    for(int i=0; i<workerCnt; i++) {
       new Thread(getS3UploadTask()).start();
    }
}
```

[Edit: of course, the above is only addressing your issue of "how to" and may be entirely irrelevant to the goal of improving uploads ;)]

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [standard thread tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html), or edit your question to explain what you need to know that's specific to s3?